# A gradle plugin to replace RoboVm for libgdx?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx, robovm

I had been using RoboVM on libgdx. I recently updated everything I had been using and had to face the fact that RoboVM is winding down.

To be honest, I was a beginner when I started LibGDX and never needed to pay attention to backend stuff. I got started with couple youtube tutorials and was I fine until recently.

For that reason I am trying to understand what is going on, and looking for a way around. I had come across with BugVM and the list on the following link: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3925

However BugVM is not decently documented yet, and I am having trouble understanding how to use any items on the list given in the link.

Could you briefly explain how do I integrate any item on the given list, or could you just push me in the right direction so that I could start learning by myself? Or could you suggest me a simple RoboVM like plugin which would work on IOS, Android and Desktop as RoboVM did? My intention is to create an application that will work on Android, IOS and Desktop (I was simply running DesktopLauncher before to test my code. Now I get "RoboVM has not been licensed for this machine." and looking for a long term solution).

At this point I am completely lost and I am eager to learn. I just need some guidance as I am trying to learn it all completely by myself for now. Any help/suggestion/explanation is very much appreciated, and I am pretty sure your response will be useful to other beginners in the future as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the so called solution in your link have been changed since then:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3934

I recommend download the latest gdx-setup.jar for libGDX 1.9.3 or later:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle

Create a new libGDX project with ios and ios-moe subprojects enabled and then look how those 2 ios backend are implemented.

After that eihter copy your old project code into a fresh setup libgdx project or rebuild the basic setup within you old code.

Comment: Just solved it, the link you have provided was helpful, thanks.